# How can I redirect after sending form to Salesforce?

Tags: javascript

I'm sending a form to a Salesforce server, but after sending it, I want to redirect to a new view.

I'm unable to achive this. I tried with this:

1.
Html:

```
<form action="https://webto.salesforce.com/..." method="POST" class="row" id="form">
    <input class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" name="submit" onsubmit="Example()">
</form>
```

Js:

```
function Example() {    
    setTimeout(function () { window.location = "http://myWeb.com/Thanks" }, 1);
};
```

2. 

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var form = document.getElementById('form');
    console.log(form);
    formulario.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);
    async function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
         const form = new FormData(this);
             response = fetch(this.action, {
                method: this.method,
                body: form,
                headers: {
                    'Accept': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://myWeb.com/'
                }
            });
            if (response.ok) {
                this.reset();
                window.location.href = 'http://myWeb.com/Thanks'
            }
    }
});
```

The new view is the typical "We will contact you", like a "Thanks"

But nothing happens, the form is sent but does not redirects me to the new view, and the Second example I have CORS failure.

The CORS failure says:

> Access to fetch at 'https://SalesForceWeb.com' from origin 'http://MyWeb:1111' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

But I'm sending data from `'http://MyWeb:1111/Home/Index'`, Can be this a problem?

I have `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://myWeb.com:1111/Home/Index'` but it attemps to send the data from `http://myWeb.com:1111/`

Comment: The second snippet is the way to go, providing the target accepts cross-origin AJAX requests. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a response header, it's not useful to set it for a request.

Comment: We can´t configure Salesforce servers, so i'm unable to send the form from my navigator because the CORS failure. `"Access to fetch at 'salesforceWeb.com' from origin 'myWebPage.com' has been blocked by CORS  policy: No 'Access-control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves you needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You MUST `await` asynchronous operations before you attempt to read their return value.

As for your CORS issue: the error message suggests that making a request to that URL is not possible unless you specify the request `mode` of `no-cors`; and even then you will get an "opaque" response (ie. containing no data), that might not be what you want.

If your code will eventually be hosted on the Salesforce domain, then this issue might disappear once deployed. [See also](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000391299&type=1).

```js
const fetch = () => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(() => res({ ok: true }), 1000)) // fake-out the fetch
const onSubmit = async ({ target }) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(target);

    const response = await fetch(target.action, { // note the await!
        method: target.method,
        body: form,
        headers: {}
    });

    if (response.ok) {
        console.log('OK');
        target.reset();
        await new Promise((res) =>  setTimeout(() => window.location.href = 'https://www.example.com', 2000)); // wait 2 seconds before redirect
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    var form = document.getElementById('form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit);        
});
```

```html
<form id="form" action="https://www.example.com" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: On this line: `await new Promise((res) =>  setTimeout(() => window.location.href = 'https://www.example.com', 2000))`, '2000' is a port?

Comment: Also, I have this problem: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at HTMLFormElement.onSubmit`

Comment: The 2000 is milliseconds to wait before the redirect, so that the resetting of the form can be observed. I have now faked the `fetch` method to avoid the issue you were seeing.

Comment: Now it redirects but not sending the form, I will see whats happening. Thanks!

Comment: Note that in my code I have faked-out `fetch`. If you are using my solution you should delete my `fetch` function.

Comment: Yes, but if I delete the `faked-out fetch` function, I have the `CORS` and `fetch` problems. I need to have a `fetch` like yout `faked-out` one?